# Is there way to measure the width of a binary mask along its length using opencv-python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have this binary mask of an image:

[image]

Is there a way to iterate along the length of the image and measure the width, like so:

[image]

I'm fairly new to image processing, so some help and guidance would really be appreciated.

Comment: With distanceTransform you will get a nice base. But you will also need a way to follow that line (best by direction and perpendicular direction). Medial axis, skeletonization, gradient-directions might help there. I don't know a generally working solution though... Not even to find the start/end of that curve.

Comment: A ridge-detection in the distanceTransform result might or might not do the trick...

Comment: Alternatively to ridge detection, consider morphological thinning of the original image.

Comment: You could do morphology erode one pixel at a time until the figure disappears. The number of iterations will tell you the thickness.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/is-there-way-to-measure-the-width-of-a-binary-mask-along-its-length/10581

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold
- Get the distance transform on copy of thresholded image
- Get the skeleton on a copy of the threshold image
- Multiply the distance image by the skeleton image
- Compute average of thickness image where skeleton is not zero
- Compute overall thickness as 2 * average
- Print result

Input:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.morphology

# read input
img = cv2.imread('s_curve.jpg')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# use thresholding
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# get distance transform
distance = thresh.copy()
distance = cv2.distanceTransform(distance, distanceType=cv2.DIST_L2, maskSize=5).astype(np.float32)

# get skeleton (medial axis)
binary = thresh.copy()
binary = binary.astype(np.float32)/255
skeleton = skimage.morphology.skeletonize(binary).astype(np.float32)

# apply skeleton to select center line of distance 
thickness = cv2.multiply(distance, skeleton)

# get average thickness for non-zero pixels
average = np.mean(thickness[skeleton!=0])

# thickness = 2*average
thick = 2 * average
print("thickness:", thick)
```

```
thickness: 28.91813850402832
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @fmw42 thanks for your help. I have tried doing this and got the same answer but I want to know what is the unit for the mean thickness? and is it possible to print or save in a text file all the thickness values along the entire length of the shape?

Comment: Unit is pixels.  I do not know at this moment if you can print it along the curve. You can print it from the thickness image (all non-zero pixel values), but it will be in scan-line order as the image is read out (first row of image, then second row of image etc).