# For binary masks with irregular shapes, Which is most reliable method to calculate mask's thickness?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[image: Knee cartilage binary mask image]

- This is a sample binary mask image of knee cartilage for which I wish to calculate it's thickness.
- Link referred: **[Is there way to measure the width of a binary mask along its length using opencv-python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74095775/is-there-way-to-measure-the-width-of-a-binary-mask-along-its-length-using-opencv)**
- I tried methodology mentioned in above link which uses distance transform and skeletonization for computing thickness. Resulting thickness was **6.18**.
  Code for above method:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.morphology

first_mask_image = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)


# Use thresholding
thresh = cv2.threshold(first_mask_image , 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Get distance transform
distance = thresh.copy()
distance = cv2.distanceTransform(distance, distanceType=cv2.DIST_L2, maskSize=5).astype(np.float32)

# Get skeleton (medial axis)
binary = thresh.copy()
binary = binary.astype(np.float32) / 255
skeleton = skimage.morphology.skeletonize(binary).astype(np.float32)


# Apply skeleton to select center line of distance 
thickness = cv2.multiply(distance, skeleton)

# Get average thickness for non-zero pixels
average = np.mean(thickness[skeleton != 0])

# Calculate thickness as 2 * average
thick = 2 * average
print("Thickness of the first mask image:", thick)
```

- I also tried Contour-based methodology in which the calculation of thickness is based on the ratio of the area to the perimeter of contours detected in a binary mask. Using this method resulting thickness was **2.47**.

Code for Contour-based method:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

first_mask_image = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Calculate contours from the binary mask
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(first_mask_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Initialize a list to store thickness values
thickness_values = []

# Iterate through each contour and compute the average thickness
for contour in contours:
    # Calculate the bounding rectangle for each contour
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    
    # Calculate the average thickness as the ratio of area to perimeter
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    thickness = area / perimeter
    
    # Append the thickness value to the list
    thickness_values.append(thickness)

# Compute the overall average thickness from all contours
average_thickness = np.mean(thickness_values)

print("Average Thickness:", average_thickness)
```

I need an advice of a person who can guide me which methodology is more reliable for calculating thickness. Also if there is another way proven to give accurate results please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think area/perimeter is just and approximation.  Look at a rectangle. The thickness is either w or h.  But area/perimeter is w*h/(2*w+2*h). So that cannot be correct.

Comment: Let's say that w > h, then area/perimeter=w*h/(2*w)=h/2. So area/perimeter is more like half the thickness.  But this relationship does not work if the w and h are about the same size (i.e. more like a square, not a long rectangle).

Comment: You can also maybe try dividing the number of white pixels in the image by the number of pixels in the medial axis (which should be 1 pixel wide). Example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66352710/2836621